# Timezone database and DST

Tags: linux, timezone

According to the [Busybox FAQ](http://www.busybox.net/FAQ.html#tz), the way timezones are managed depends on my system's libc.  For my embedded system, if I want to change the timezone, I need to create a symbolic link from `/etc/localtime` to a TZ database file like so:

`/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+2`

My question is about the TZ database.

What's the difference between, say, `Asia/Jerusalem` and `Etc/GMT+2` since it's in the timezone `GMT+2` anyway?.  Or; what's the difference between `Australia/Melbourne` and `GMT+11`?

I've noticed that say, Melbourne, for example, is in `GMT+11` for 6 months of the year, and `GMT+10` for the remaining 6 months of the year.

Is that the difference between symbolic linking to a *city name*  in the TZ databse, and linking to a GMT version (eg. `Etc/GMT+11`)?  Does linking to a city name mean that DST adjustments are automatically taken care of, but for the GMT version it is not?

Thankyou so much guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: Since you asked in the context of Busybox, this isn't exactly [on-topic for Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  However, I'll go ahead and answer it anyway, since there are many other questions about the TZ database here related to programming, and this is applicable in the general case.*

A named time zone such as `Asia/Jerusalem` reflects time in a geographic region.  The reference point is usually (but not always) a city, and it's usually (but not always) the most *populous* city in the region - not necessarily the capital city.

Within this geographic region, all history of time zone changes are tracked.  This includes both daylight saving time changes and base-offset changes.  There can be *many* changes within a single time zone over its history.  You can view the rich detail of these changes in the tzdb source code.  For example, [here is the entry for Israel](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2015a/asia#L1139-L1366).

Fixed-offset entries like `Etc/GMT-2` are primarily in the TZDB for backwards compatibility purposes.  You'll find them in the [etcetera file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera).  They are not for any particular geographic region, and thus do not have any daylight saving time rules.

Also note that because they were created for backwards compatibility with older POSIX standards, the sign of these offsets are *inverted* from what they would normally be.  Thus, `Asia/Jerusalem` would actually align with `Etc/GMT-2` during standard time, and `Etc/GMT-3` during daylight time.

In general, you should only use the named time zones.  You can find a list of them [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Thanks Matt!   I also just discovered the `zdump` utility.  I noticed that when I use `zdump` on a city, I get entries as far back as 1901, but never more recent than this year (2015).  Shouldn't each database have entries for 2016, 2017, and so on, for when those years arrive?

Comment: You might ask about Linux tools like zdump on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).  You might also get more relevant answers asking in [the tz discussion mailing list](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Comment: In general though - rules are only created when there is reliable information.  Nobody can see into the future to predict what governments of the world will do.  The tzdb reflects information as it is presently known.  In some cases, the future rules have been determined - and in some cases it's just assumed that the current rule will continue until a change is announced.